# How exactly are natural relations interpreted mathematically (See details)?

Tags: functions, intuition

Why is it that when two physical quantities are directly proportional to a third one, we **multiply** the 1st with the 2nd, equaling the 3rd? (F=ma)
 Why do we not, for instance, add them?

How can we possibly figure out if such relations contain square roots, variables raised to powers, or any other specific mathematical operations?

Comment: When talking about physics, the way you figure these things out is by doing experiments.

Comment: A first reason I see is that many physically meaningful quantities appear naturally at first not as products but as **ratios** C=A/B from which you deduce laws under a product form A=BC.

Comment: Also, when you say two things $x,y$ are proportional w.r.t. a third one $A$, this is just defined to mean $xy=A$. So there's no 'reason' other then this is just the way it is defined.

Comment: You are asking a simple question with a very deep answer. A useful tool when working in the sciences is to keep track of the units of the involved quantities. Often, the units will make it clear in what ways things can and cannot relate to one another. For instance, $F=ma$ because force is measured in $\frac{g\cdot m}{s^2}$, and mass is measured in $g$ and acceleration in $\frac{m}{s^2}$, hence to get force, you take the product of mass and acceleration. (Rule of thumb: let the units be your guide.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is exactly what *directly proportional*, as you said, means.

> Why do we not, for instance, add them?

It's easy to construct an experiment to show that $F = m + a$ is indeed often wrong.

> How can we possibly figure out if such relations contain ... variables raised to powers, ...

For example in Kepler's second law:

$$\frac{P^2}{a^3} = C$$
(where $C \approx \frac{4 \pi}{GM}$)

These relationships are discovered through careful experiments, noting the data, and finding mathematical descriptions that fit. Usually, often, we also try to find a motivation for why the relationship looks like this.